# How check if a post is saved from backend or frontend?

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks, save-post

I created a *custom post type* called `wasb_contact` which can be inserted and edited both from the backend and from the frontend (through a form I created).
The *CPT* has some custom meta fields which are saved by a function called `wasb_contact_save_postdata` and invoked by the `save_post_{$post->post_type}` hook. I would like this function to be invoked only when the *CPT* is created or modified from the backend and not also when it is created or modified from the frontend.

How can I do?

Comment: I'd try [is_admin()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/) if you haven't already, but I don't know if that'll still be true from the frontend depending on how you're including the admin files to update the posts.

Comment: To be creatable/editable from the frontend you need some custom code, right? Why not add a flag / specific setting in there, so you know when this is not present, the request is coming from the backend.

Comment: I tried with is_admin() but it doesn't work in my case.

There isn't a better way than add a flag?

Comment: I'm surprised - how is current_screen getting set in your front-end form? How about `if ( defined( 'WP_ADMIN' ) )` ? But this all depends on how you've set up the front end form I suppose.

Comment: @Rup it's a simple HTML form in a template. Can you explain the correct use of is_admin(), current_screen, etc, please?

Comment: OK, so you're not requiring lots of code from wp-admin? Then is_admin() should work fine. If you do `if ( is_admin() ) { ... }` in your filter then that should be true if the code is run from the backend but false if you've submitted your front end form.

Comment: @Rup I don't know why, maybe my mistake but `is_admin()` always return true, both if I save post from backend and backend.

Comment: Why don't you set a metafield or flag from the save hook in the backend? Then you could grab that lateron and compare that when needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would add some hidden input field to frontend form, and check for its presence in the save_post hook.

```
...
<input type="hidden" name="saved-on-frontend" value="1">
...
```

And then check for it in that hooked function:

```
function my_save_hook() {

    if( isset( $_POST['saved-on-frontend'] ) ) {
        return; // don't do anything ... 
    }

}
add_action( 'save_post_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE', 'my_save_hook' );
```